# Concatenate numpy arrays to a single array

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to merge the two <class 'numpy.ndarray'> into a single array.

Code that I tried:

```
for emb in embs:
   print(np.concatenate( emb['name'], axis=0 ))
```

Input:

```
[[-0.05646843 -0.00381141 -0.05721215 0.06029008]
 [-0.02690301  0.04218878  0.00404305 0.05841358]]
[[-0.02675129  0.03649405 -0.04379312 -0.04826404]
 [ 0.01131434  0.0581139   0.00785002  -0.02065904]]
```

Output:

```
[[-0.05646843 -0.00381141 -0.05721215 0.06029008]
 [-0.02690301  0.04218878  0.00404305 0.05841358]
 [-0.02675129  0.03649405 -0.04379312 -0.04826404]
 [ 0.01131434  0.0581139   0.00785002  -0.02065904]]
```

Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't really get this question. Will you please provide more detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question has several problems.

What is `embs`; we can guess, such as a list of `dict`, or maybe pandas dataframe?

What is the block labeled `input`?  The result of this loop:

```
for emb in embs: 
   print(emb['name'])
```

What is `output`?  That actual output of your code, or the desired output?  If the latter, what did your code do?  What was wrong with it?

Often we see naive attempts to replicate this list iteration:

```
alist = []
for x in another_list:
    alist.append(x)
```

But I'm not sure that's what you have in mind.  You don't define any array to 'collect' the loop values in.  And your loop just has a `print()`, which doesn't return anything (or rather returns `None`).  And `concatenate` doesn't work in in-place.

You've read enough of the `concatenate` docs to use the `axis` parameter, but your single first argument looks nothing like the documented tuple of arrays, `(a1, a2, ...)`

Since `embs` is apparently a list of 2 somethings with a `name` value, and the values are matching 2d arrays, this `concatenate` should produce your desired `output`:

```
np.concatenate( (embs[0]['name'], embs[1]['name']), axis=0 )
```

We could make that argument tuple with a list comprehension, or my earlier list append, but I think you need to see this concatenation spelled out in detail.  Your understanding of python loops is still weak.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print(np.concatenate([emb['name'] for emb in embs]))
```

Answer (score 0):

input :

```py
data1 = [[-0.05646843 ,-0.00381141,  -0.05721215, 0.06029008],
         [-0.02690301 , 0.04218878 , 0.00404305, 0.05841358]]

data2 = [[-0.02675129 , 0.03649405, -0.04379312, -0.04826404],
         [ 0.01131434 , 0.0581139 ,  0.00785002 , -0.02065904]]
```

output:

```py
concatenated_data = np.concatenate((np.array(data1),np.array(data2)))

print(concatenated_data)
```